# Prevent redirect when calling url_for in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to pass a url string to a view from one of my controller methods, like so:

```
def index
    @locals = {table_cols: $config['global_fields'],
               table_title: $config['main_page']['table_title'],
               ajax: url_for(action: index_data)}} # HERE
end
```

index_data is a function in my controller that returns some data in JSON format.  However, when I navigate to the index page of my application, the browser simply displays the JSON output of index_data.

I'm assuming calling url_for within index is redirecting that page to index_data - is there a way to prevent this and just have url_for return the string, e.g. '/controller/index_data'?

Thanks

Comment: Why is `$config` a global variable? That's pretty reckless.

Comment: @tadman - that is for my controller-level config.  Sorry, I'm very new to ruby/rails.  Do you have a suggestion on how to improve?

Comment: It's usually better to put that sort of stuff in your application's module, like `MyApp.config['global_fields']` where you can add a `config` method to `lib/my_app.rb` or what have you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you are calling the `index_data` action when you attempt to get a url to it, and calling it is tricking Rails into thinking you want to render from that action.

If you change your `url_for` to point to a symbol (or string) instead of the return value of the action, things will probably start working as you expect:

```
@locals = { ..., ajax: url_for(action: :index_data)}}
```